# How to get Documents in a Library to Automatically Delete after [x] Days

Tags: sharepoint-online, document

Is there a way that we can get a command to get documents to automatically delete after Said amount of days?

Answer (score 1):

This can be configured in the document library settings. Click the link for Information Management policy settings. In here, create a new policy that will delete a file after X number of days.

[image]

Then weekly, a series of timer jobs will 1) mark the appropriate files for deletion 2) go through and delete them. Based on the execution of these timer jobs, it may take up tp 2 weeks for the files to be purged.